# Fill cell based on condition

Tags: excel, vba, autofill

Im not programmer and im looked internet for solutions, but i couldn't find.
I need macro with autofill cells based on column with condition.

I have data in excel in sheet "Order":

```
WorkOrder  ID          Item2       Column4    Level3   NewColumn   
Number4    TOPLEVEL    Jonas       Station1   5
212121212  2           Station1    5          2
31212121   3           Station1    1          4
...         ...         ...         ...        ...

TextSome   TOPLEVEL    Jonas       Station1   5         
212121212  2           Station1    5          2
31212121   3           Station1    1          4
...         ...         ...         ...        ...
```

I need macro, when in column ID="TOPLEVEL", then add value from WorkOrder to NewColumn and fill rows in this column to next ID="TOPLEVEL". Like This:

```
WorkOrder  ID          Item2       Column4    Level3   NewColumn   
Number4    TOPLEVEL    Jonas       Station1   5        Number4
212121212  2           Station1    5          2        Number4
31212121   3           Station1    1          4        Number4
...         ...         ...         ...        ...     Number4
                                                       Number4
TextSome   TOPLEVEL    Jonas       Station1   5        TextSome 
212121212  2           Station1    5          2        TextSome 
31212121   3           Station1    1          4        TextSome 
...         ...         ...         ...        ...     TextSome
```

Any one can help me with this issue ?

Answer (score 0):

Without going into VBA solutions, you can do this through an Excel Function. A very simple example is to put the following formula in cell E2.

```
=IF(B2="TOP LEVEL",A2,E1)
```

And then fill-down - the numbers will auto-adjust. I have assumed that the columns above are columns A-E and that you have started at row 1 - if your sheet is different then adjust B2, A2 and E1 accordingly.

Simple explanation: if the row is "TOP LEVEL" then copy the ID, if not then copy the code from the line above because we have assumed that your data is structured properly and that the line above is copied from a previous "TOP LEVEL" row.

Comment: i know this trick, but i need automated this action, because this table is web query. that why i need macro

Comment: @SevaArve : You can create a VBA solution to do the equivalent of the above formula. You can also create a VBA solution to insert the above formula into the sheet after putting the web query results in.

Comment: where add this function after web query result in macro ?

Comment: I don't work with web queries myself, but look for an event that indicates the web query has completed. Then you can create a custom event handler in the appropriate object that runs this function. Again, not working with the web queries I don't know if it is a simple Worksheet_Change or something else.